# Équivalent de l'argot écossais « tartle »

Tags: traduction, anglais

[Référence: Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Tartle) :

> A common Scottish term to insert at the awkward moment when you
> temporarily forget someone's name. Useful to avoid that occasional
> embarrassment.

Exemple :

> Steve: Hi, Susan!
>
> Susan: Hi . . . uhhhhhh . . . Steve! Sorry, I *tartled* there for a moment.

See also [here](https://europeisnotdead.com/europe-is-not-deadfr/disco/mots-europeens/mots-intraduisibles-europeens/) :

> Tartle– Voici un mot bien amusant venant d’Ecosse qui désigne l’acte
> d’hésiter lorsque l’on présente quelqu'un parce que l’on a oublié son
> nom.

Quel mot ou expression peut-on utiliser dans un tel contexte pour transmettre une idée voisine ?

Exemple :

> Steve: Salut, Susan!
>
> Susan: Salut . . . uhhhhhh . . . Steve! Désolé, j'ai hésité (?) pour un moment.

Comment: Pourquoi un « -1 » à cette question ? Quelqu'un qui le sache ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je ne connais pas de mot spécifique pour la perte de mémoire des noms, mais on pourra dire :

> Désolé, j'ai eu un trou (pendant un instant).

[Trou](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/trou) (TLFi):

> B. − Domaine abstr.
>   1. Défaillance momentanée de la mémoire concernant un fait précis à se remémorer.

Answer (score 1):

Le mot courant suivant peut être utilisé : « échapper ».

> (TLFi)  En partic. Sortir de la mémoire. René Fitament et son compagnon, dont le nom m'échappe

- Désolé, le nom m'échappe. Désolé, votre nom m'échappe.

L'expression « avoir un trou de mémoire » s'utilise aussi. C'est moins utilisé que « j'ai un trou », mais c'est d'un registre soutenu, ce qui n'est pas le cas de l'expression raccourcie.